# Chi-square in genetics with fruit flies. Getting 0 observed when the expected was more than 0, and got an unexpected phenotype. How to handle?

Tags: chi-squared-test, genetics

We crossed fruit flies in genetics class and I ended up with very different results than the expected values. For some values, I had 0 observed when the expected was more than 0. Would I go through with the statistical analysis and just do (0-E)^2/E? And I also got an unexpected phenotype not anticipated in the punnett square. Do I incorporate it into the chi square statistical analysis, and if so how? Since it doesn't have a ratio provided by the punnett square.